# HTTP Status 404 -> The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat9

So, i was writing a login page for my website and i added a few new interfaces and servlets, when i went to test **none** of my .jsp files where working, i was getting a 404 error.

eventually i tried to rename them to .html to see if that did anything, it didn't, i also tried to remove some code to see if it was incorrect code, eventually i realised it was probably my web.xml, i'm not the greatest with anything todo with xml, i kind of hate it, anyways, i've been stuck here for 6 hours now.

````xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>PowerBoot</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>club.powerboot.website.Servlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Login</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>club.powerboot.website.login.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>CheckCredits</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CheckCredits</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>club.powerboot.website.login.CheckCredits</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CheckCredits</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CheckCredits</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ConnectDatabase</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ConnectDatabase</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>club.powerboot.website.sql.ConnectDatabase</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ConnectDatabase</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ConnectDatabase</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>SQLConnection</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SQLConnection</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>club.powerboot.website.sql.SQLConnection</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SQLConnection</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SQLConnection</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Provider</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Provider</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>club.powerboot.website.sql.Provider</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Provider</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Provider</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginRegister</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginRegister</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>club.powerboot.website.login.LoginRegister</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginRegister</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginRegister</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Register</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>club.powerboot.website.login.Register</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginHandler</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>club.powerboot.website.login.LoginHandler</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>RegisterLogin</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RegisterLogin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>club.powerboot.website.login.RegisterLogin</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterLogin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/registerLogin</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>```

I just want to know why this issue is occurring so i can try to avoid it in the future.
````

Comment: Did you check the Tomcat log files?

Comment: @Andreas i looked but there are no recent logs.

Comment: There are always logs. Look again. --- Or fix whatever file/folder security issue you have that is preventing log creation. --- If there are no logs, are you sure Tomcat is even running? 404 is also what you'd see when Tomcat isn't running.

Comment: I am using eclipse to start the tomcat server, i went into the logs folder but the only logs are from 2 days ago, i am not too sure what would be preventing log creation, to be fair, this is my first ever web project.

Comment: After reviewing my code i think it has something todo with this class - https://hastebin.com/dugiceqaso.java